# DropShadowEffect after Rotation in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a polygon which represents the needle on a gauge. The needle is rotated according to the current value on the gauge.

The needle casts a shadow using the DropShadowEffect, but the shadow rotates with the needle, because the shadow is generated before the RenderTransformation is performed.

This is the XAML for the polygon

```
  <Polygon Points="3,1 -3,1 -2,-60 0,-100 2,-60">
    <Polygon.RenderTransform>
      <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform>
          <ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiplyConverter}">
              <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding ElementName="InnerEllipse" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                <Binding Source="0.0045"/>
              </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
          </ScaleTransform.ScaleY>
        </ScaleTransform>
        <RotateTransform>
          <RotateTransform.Angle>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AngleConverter}">
              <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding Path="Ratio"                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding Path="ParentGauge.StartAngle" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding Path="ParentGauge.EndAngle"   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
              </MultiBinding.Bindings>
            </MultiBinding>
          </RotateTransform.Angle>
        </RotateTransform>
      </TransformGroup>
    </Polygon.RenderTransform>
    <Polygon.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0.5" StartPoint="1,0.5">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource LightenOrDarkenColor}, ConverterParameter=0.2}" Offset="0.462"/>
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Color, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource LightenOrDarkenColor}, ConverterParameter=-0.2}" Offset="0.552"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Polygon.Fill>
    <Polygon.Effect>
      <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
    </Polygon.Effect>
  </Polygon>
```

Is there any way that I can make it generate the shadow after performing the rotation, so that the shadow comes from a consistent direction?

**Edit**

By the way, I know that I can define the Direction for the DropShadowEffect and I guess that I could bind it to the value of the gauge, such that it rotates in the opposite direction, but I thought there might be a simpler and more elegant method.

Comment: Generally I would advise against using shader effects in such a way for potential performance issues. However for the sake of the question, I could only see doing this by building out a pretty custom control that watches the transform of the needle and applies corresponding values to the effect to render via HLSL. Unless you could instead opt to instead use something like Viewport3D with a light source to do the heavy lifting of the effect for you. However, you're playing in a hardware accelerated environment that may not play nice on all machines. Either way, this is a really broad question.

Comment: Could you not apply the Effect in the code behind on a particular event? I would assume something like an onChanged or an event that comes after your needle update? similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022746/wpf-add-a-dropshadow-effect-to-an-element-from-code-behind)

Comment: This is in a ControlTemplate for a custom control, so that is not entirely practical. The code would have to be in the controls code. So far this is a "lookless" control, so I really want to keep the UI design in XAML.